# Install Rsyslog with omkafka module on CentOS 5 32 bit

Tags: apache-kafka, 32-bit, rsyslog, centos5

How to install **Rsyslog** with **omkafka** module on **CentOS 5 32 bit** ?

I want to enable omkafka module in Rsyslog on centos 5 32 bit. I am currently using Rsyslog 8.16.0 version, and when I run, under rsyslog folder, this command `"./configure --enable-omkafka"`. I get error `"could not find rdkafka library"`. But I can't find a librdkafka library for 32 bit arch!

Comment: check this https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-full-featured-rsyslog-5.7.x-on-centos-5.x

Comment: Please ask specific questions....if you have any problem somewhere or you are stuck while installing the same. This is very open ended question and simple googling would have got you some answers.